# What happens internally when `ls *.c` is executed?

Tags: linux, shell, linux-kernel, wildcard

I've got very interested in Linux internals recently, and currently trying to understand how things work.

I knew that when I type `ls`

- `opendir()` - function is called;
- `readdir()` - function called for each directory entry in directory data store;
- `stat()` - function can be called to get additional information on files, if required.

Please correct me if I'm missing something or if it's wrong.

The part which is mystery to me is filename expansion(globbing).

I've compared the output of `strace ls`

```
open(".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=270336, ...}) = 0
getdents(3, /* 14 entries */, 32768)    = 440
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 1), ...}) = 0
write(1, "2q.c  ds.c  fglob  fnoglob\n", 272q.c  ds.c  fglob  fnoglob
```

and `strace ls *.c`,

```
stat("2q.c", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
lstat("2q.c", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("ds.c", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
lstat("ds.c", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
write(1, "2q.c  ds.c\n", 112q.c  ds.c
)            = 11
```

and from my limited knowledge can tell that in the first case, it indeed behaves as I expected `open, stat` followed by `getdents`.

But the later one, with shell globbing isn't clear to me, because it there's already a list of files, which match the pattern. Where does this list came from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shell globbing patterns on the command line are expanded by the shell *before* the utility is invoked.

You can see this by enabling tracing in the shell with `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ ls -l f*
+ ls -l file1 file2 file3
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 May 11 16:49 file1
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 May 11 16:49 file2
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 May 11 16:49 file3
```

As you can see, the shell tells you what command it invokes (at the `+` prompt), and at that point it has already expanded the pattern on the command line.

The `ls` command does not do filename globbing. In fact, if you single quote the globbing pattern to protect it from the shell, `ls` is bound to be confused:

```
$ ls -l 'f*'
+ ls -l f*
ls: f*: No such file or directory
```

(unless there's actually something in the current directory called `f*` of course).

Comment: @akmal Turn it off with `set +x`.